# Need to implementation AWS S3 Bucket file upload using c#. Whereas file size is not limit

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

i have a requirement to upload file in AWS S3 bucket using c#, In which i have list of file to upload one time. My client send me only that for

( S3  : arn:aws:iam::3**********9:user/intl-in-livestreaming-user-prod)

credential.After upload file create URL of that file to seen from anywhere or download it through link.
Help me because i have no any idea about that first time i get that AWS work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to upload a file to your bucket in Amazon S3, you would need to import their AWSSDK package from your Nuget manager. Once you have done that, you can use this piece of code to get your file uploaded. Please note that you would require the `awsAccessKeyId`, `awsSecretAccessKey` and the region endpoint when you setup your AmazonS3Client object. Once you do that, you would require the name of the bucket you want to upload your file to. Please ensure that the bucket has the required access to accept files from outside source.

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;

  using (var client = new AmazonS3Client("awsAccessKeyId", 
               "awsSecretAccessKey", RegionEndpoint.{yourregionendpoint}))
    {
      PutObjectRequest objReq = new PutObjectRequest
     {
         Key = "FolderName"+"/"+"ImageOne", //If you create folder inside bucket then you use key otherwise without key also upload data successfully.
         FilePath = "E:\\blah\\imageone.jpg",
         BucketName = "your bucket name",
         CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private,
     };

        PutObjectResponse response = s3newClient.PutObject(objReq);
        if (response.ETag != null)
           {
            string etag = response.ETag;
            string versionID = response.VersionId;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But, client wants ..."Upload File from Windows to S3 using AWS CLI"  AWS CLI using c#.

Comment: Have you tried this piece of code? Also there is no mention of AWS CLI in original question.

Comment: yes i forgot to mention that point. Ok, no issue but one most important thing is that every file when going to upload they first create folder same as filename inside bucket and then upload inside of that folder.Can we do that thing using your code ,whereas code is working fine.Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: My friend.... S3 buckets do not have to concept of directories. If you want your file to be placed in a directory structure, then you can add it in the Key option like this: Key: "yourfoldername"+"/"+"yourfilename". Also if this solution helped you out,  you can mark it as correct. :).

Comment: Thanks, i m trying your code. I will response you is working or not from that case.

Comment: Hi friend above code are not working while give all parameters.

Comment: Okay. Can you debug and see where the error is happening ? It is most probably that your bucket does not have the required access. Please check.

Comment: while debugging no any error come, it execute the code but no file upload in AWS. Whereas i am using AWS CLI to upload then its uploaded.

Comment: @amitkumar Can you double check that. What kind of file are you uploading? Can you post that code here without your `awsAccessKeyId` and `awsSecretAccessKey` . If the file is not being uploaded then there has to be some error. If there is no error then it has to do with the way you are putting your file in the `MemoryStream`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197870/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-rahul-sharma).